# 'Cannot find DAO350.dll' file error VB6

Tags: vb6, windows-8.1

After installing VB6 successfully on my Windows 8.1 64bit pc, whenever i am trying to open my `.vbp` project file it gives me an error `can't find DAO350.dll file`. Googled for every possible solution but couldn't find one.

[image]

Please help me.

[UPDATE]

[image]

[UPDATE1]: It looks something like this[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The DA0350.dll must be registered.
Try this:

On the Visual Basic 6.0 CD (or whatever your installation source is), locate the Dao350.dll file, and then copy it to the directory c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\DAO. (The Dao350.dll file is located in the \os\system folder on the Visual Basic 6.0 CD.)

To register this file, click Start, click Run, and then type or paste the following line:

```
Regsvr32 "c:\program files (x86)\common files\microsoft shared\DAO\Dao350.dll"
```

Update:

The `VB6TMPL.TLB` is probably not installed for your current user.
Try to run Visual Basic as administrator and/or try this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262976/en-us

Comment: Thats where i am confused. In my PC, c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\DAO , the `DAO` folder is missing. What should i do.?

Comment: I'd try adding the folder.

Comment: Wrong directory, it needs to be `c:\program files (x86)`.  And it needs to be the 32-bit version of Regsvr32, located in c:\windows\syswow64.  And needs to be executed from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: So @HansPassant you mean that i should run `Regsvr32 c:\program files (x86)\common files\microsoft shared\DAO\Dao350.dll` from cmd(with administator rights) ?

Comment: I missed the x64 part, sorry.

What Hans said. :)

Comment: Ok. My bad forgot to put "" with the statement. Correct statement was `Regsvr32 "C:\program files (x86)\common files\microsoft shared\DAO\Dao350.dll"`. But after that when i run my `.vbp` file, it gives me some different error. Pasting it in UPDATE part.

Comment: Please check the key in registry path "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{FCFB3D2E-A0FA-1068-A738-08002B3371B5}\6.0\9\win32". Does it point to the location where your "vb6.olb"-file is located?

Comment: The key looks good. Does the file exist on that path?
Also, what does happen if you start VB6 as administrator?

Comment: That is an unspecific error about a missing binary. Does vb6 on load show that error and shut down or does it happen when you try to compile or run the project? Also, did you install the latest service pack for vb6? it can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5721. To be honest i am in the dark with the latest error. Maybe @HansPassant can help.

Comment: I'd love to join you on chat but sadly i can't duo to company proxy restrictions. As you accepted the answer, is the problem solved?

Comment: I doubt my boss will pay me for debugging support, sadly. Bad enough i'm answering on stackoverflow at all while at work. If you have specific issues just make another post. Someone will help you most likely (maybe me? who knows?) as vb6 is quite old and well known.

Answer (score 1):

To solve about "Can't find file DAO350.DLL"

1. Download DAO350.DLL file from https://www.dll-files.com/dao350.dll.html
2. Extract file DLL, then copy file DAO350.DLL to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98 or any other place you install VB 6
3. Try open your VB 6

Work for me.

Answer (score 1):

From the command prompt, execute the following commands:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO
regsvr32 dao350.dll
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 1):

On the **Visual Basic 6.0** CD (or whatever your installation source is), locate the Dao350.dll file, and then copy it to the directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98.

After applying this fix. The Visual Basic 6 can now run successfully on your Computer.

NOTE: The Dao350.dll file is located in the \os\system folder on the Visual Basic 6.0 CD.