# Cannot install VB6 IDE on Windows 10

Tags: vb6, windows-10, installation, setup.exe

I'm encountering a problem when trying to install VB6 on Windows 10. I've tried several different installers and guides but no matter what, i cannot start the `setup.exe`

Nothing happens whenever i start it. However when i check the windows events i see that the setup quits with errorcode: `0xc0000005`

I've even tried an external Installer Helper but it always happens the same way. I also cleaned up my registry before installing.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to install from a CD, you might want to try converting its content to Inno Setup. That's what solved our issues when we were installing the VB6 IDE Enterprise Edition on Windows 10.

Here's a guide on how you can do it. http://www.planetsourcecode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=74428&lngWId=1#zip
... Just click "Download code" and follow the README.txt.
We used the script VB6-generic.iss

Comment: I've read tons of tutorials on this but this is the only thing that worked for me, thank you Paolo!

Answer (score 7):

The VB6 development environment runs just fine on Windows-10, with a couple of exceptions, but to be successful, the installation procedure is not quite obvious.  I'm pasting in the text file that contains the instructions I use when installing on Win-10 systems, and which has been completely reliable. The real issue you're having is attempting to install the ADO and RDS DB providers (as noted in the missive below).  Deselecting those (despite dire warnings from the installation program) will let your installation proceed normally to the end.  But read the whole thing - there's other useful tidbits in here, too:

[How to install Visual Studio 6 onto Windows 10](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2454614-how-to-install-visual-studio-6-onto-windows-10)
Thanks to Locutus, Oct 20, 2015

Yes you read that right. I did specifically mention Visual Studio 6 in the title. That's because I am both an old codger and Visual Studio 6 is still in wide use around the world. I myself learned BASIC before there was any such thing as DOS and Visual Basic 6 is arguably the best version before they corrupted it with this dot net stuff.

There are many tutorials around the net for installing this suite into windows 7/8x but none work for windows 10. There is one program which claims to support installing visual studio 6 in windows 10 but I did not want to register just to download that program and try it out.

All of the other methods involve creating a zero byte file in the windows directory (msjava.dll) which does NOT work on windows 10. In any case you do not need to do even that trick.

First of all you need to somehow obtain a copy of visual studio 6. There are many ways of obtaining that however, I will assume (yes I know about assume yada yada) that you have a legal copy and product key.

Those files need to be on a modifiable medium. In other words if your copy is on a CDROM then you need to copy them to a folder on your disk.

The next step is to find and open up in notepad the file setupwiz.ini. Under the [setup wizard] heading there should be a line like "VmPath=ie4\msjavx86.exe". If there is not it doesn't matter. In the end you need to either modify that existing line or add a line and it must look like "VmPath=". Don't forget to save that file.

What this does is create an empty environment variable and stops the setup program for looking for the super old version of java. This fixes what the zero byte msjava.dll cludge doesn't.

After that you can start installing. Make sure you right click on the "setup.exe" file and run it as administrator. Go through all the click this and click that and put in your legal product code until you come to the screen with the setup options.

You need to select the custom setup option because otherwise you will be up a brown smelly creek in a barbed wire canoe with a tennis racket as a paddle. Ok, maybe I embellished a bit but select the custom setup option ok?

The next screen is to select the installation folder. It most probably will have as a default "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common". Get rid of the "(x86)" and install it to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common".

This apparently helps for the data access components. Remember, in those times there was not 64/32 bit thunking requiring separate program folders. Heck, in those days 32 bit was cutting edge and like the 640k memory limit it was not thought that more would be needed.

There will be more click this and that which nobody then or today takes any notice of until we come to the important screen, the one where you can select your components. This may take a while to appear while the setup program searches for installed components. Be patient :)

As I am only interested in VB6 I deselected C++, Foxpro, Interdev and source safe then selected graphics for the cool retro icons and animation, aaah nostalgia. Everything else I left as default except for one very important step.

If this is not done then the setup will go into an endless loop at the end and leave your CPU fan screaming for mercy. What you need to do is go into the "Data Access" change options, go into the "ADO,RDS and OLE DB providers" change options then deselect "ADO and RDS". The setup program will give a big scary warning so just click on it without reading like any other window which pops up.

Then click on "OK" back to the main component selection screen and "Continue" to let the setup program show it's self advertising screens while it copies the files.

If you have windows firewall activated it will want to allow access to some program. I denied that access as I didn't want it traipsing around my network without my permission. Who knows what it will do.

It will then want to restart windows which you should do because once windows has restarted the setup will continue on and want to install MSDN and other tools. None of which I installed. It may complain that "APEMREG" may not have installed correctly. You just tell windows that it did and to stop bothering you.

The final thing to do, once the install has finished and you want visual basic 6 to at least run fast, is to go the the installed directory at  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98" right click on "vb6.exe" and in the properties under the compatibility tab for all users, select compatibility mode (XP sp2) and set the settings for Reduced color mode (16bit) and disable the display scaling on high dpi settings.

Ok, the real final and never needed to be done again step is to run the VB6 program once as an administrator. This is so the final registry doo dads can be set.

That is the end of that! You can now program on a modern 64 bit operating system using a 32 bit program with 16 bit graphics and 8 bit variables for as many bits'o'cash as you can make :)

Modifications Required for VB6 Applications to Work on Vista/7/10
Thanks to Hassan Basri in VBForums

Application Changes
Remove SendKeys calls and replace them with API code.
Use the HKEY_CURRENT_USER in the registry for the settings of your application.
Do not write to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.
If you are using ADO use 2.8 and above in your application.
If you are using XML use XML version 3.0 and above in your application
If you are using the PlaySound API, if your wave files are not PCM but mpeg layer-3 make sure your mpeg wave files are Stereo and not Mono.
If you need the Printer Setup dialog either using the Common Dialog Control, or by using the API functions, the dialog will not return the correct number of copies. The dialog will always return 1 on Vista. The way around this bug is to create your own Printer Setup dialog box and when you get the correct number of copies you will have to send to the printer multiple times to print out multiple copies. Here is a link that discusses this issue in details. http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=456940
Relocate settings files, data files etc into "Common Files" (C:UsersPublic) instead of "Program Files". You should use the API calls to locate these folders because the folders are in different paths for different machines and OSs. Here is a link that discusses this issue in details. [http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=461613[/URL]](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=461613%5B/URL%5D)
Per-user settings should be in a separate file located under "Application Data" and this should also be requested of the OS in the same manner.
For "Common Files" ask for ssfCOMMONDATA (or CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA).
For "Application Data" ask for ssfAPPDATA (or CSIDL_APPDATA). To properly use these filesystem locations you are supposed to create a subdirectory for your "company name" and under that another for your "application name." Then put your settings or data under that.
Any working "document" files that are meant to be found and manipulated by the user (i.e. via Explorer) should be placed into CSIDL_PERSONAL ("My Documents") or CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS ("All UsersDocuments").
DeleteSetting no longer works without a key. e.g. DeleteSetting "Mytestprogram, "General" fails to delete anything and gives an error. but DeleteSetting "Mytestprogram, "General","keyname" works fine. It seems that key is no longer Optional in: DeleteSetting appname, section[, key] as in documentation. Another incompatibility with vista (64)is the Deletesettings no longer works without a key. Credit: roylow
Setup Package Changes

Administrator Account running your Setup Package require users to "Run as Administrator" directly in your setup package.
Inform users to right-click the setup package and click "Run As Administrator".

Non-Administrator Account running your Setup Package
Remove the VB6 Runtime files, MDAC and any of these files from your setup package.

Note: If you get the error:
Setup Error
Setup was unable to create a DCOM user account in order to register \Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\Tools\VS-Ent98\Vanalyzr\valec.exe”
Click Enterprise Tools, and then click Change Option. Under Options, make sure the Visual Studio Analyzer check box is not selected.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50175857/381082

Also if you get the error: "Can't find file DAO350.DLL", Download DAO350.DLL file from https://www.dll-files.com/dao350.dll.html
Extract file DLL, then copy file DAO350.DLL to c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\DAO\Dao350.dll. Register the program using powershell: Regsvr32 c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\DAO\Dao350.dll
See: ['Cannot find DAO350.dll' file error VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377365/cannot-find-dao350-dll-file-error-vb6)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this tutorial still doesn't fix my problem. I followed the tutorial but again, i get stuck in the beginning as i cannot start the setup.exe 
I added the VmPath= line and started as admin but still whenever i start the setup nothing happens and in windows events i see it exits with this 0xc0000005 code. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, it appears that your copy of setup.exe may be corrupted in some way (or one of the support files).  Exit code 5 is an access violation, such as will occur with memory allocation, stack/heap, or array access problems.  If it was your program, you could go searching, but for the setup program...