# INSTALLING VB6 ENTERPRISE EDITION ON WINDOWS 10

Tags: vb6

I am having problems installing VB6 Enterprise Edition on my Windows 10 computer. It is to replace my existing VB6 Learning Edition. I have uninstalled all the old VB6 files as far as I am aware, restarted with a Clean Boot, and tried to install using Windows XP SP3 compatibility mode. It goes as far as Searching For Installed Components and then just goes into a continuous loop. The only way I can stop it is by shutting down the computer. If I put the curser over the setup image on the Task Bar, I see a Message Box on the bottom right corner of the screen that says "C:...MSDESIGNERS98\MDT2GKOR.DLL" and a progress bar showing 100%. If I attempt to put a curser on it it just disappears. So that is presumably where it the setup is hanging. Does anyone know of a way around it please?

Comment: VB6, is unfortunately, not supported on Windows 10. It's time to think of migration to higher versions.

Comment: @WhirlMind VB6 runs fine on Windows 10.  I have done so for many years.

Comment: There are several things you must do to successfully install VB6.  The link provided by @GSerg should give you the information you need.

Comment: Not sure if this the right place or not but thank you everyone who has responded to my plee for help. And a special thank you to  https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248161/mark-moulding. I followed your instructions to the letter and now have VB6 Enterprise installed amongst the other computer programs and appears to work fine. Just one thing, where you said to delete the (x86) from the installed program directory, it did revert back to the (x86) but appears to work fine. Thanks again.

Bob May

Comment: @BOBMAY I guess you mean https://stackoverflow.com/a/52015989/3195477. You should upvote that answer if you haven't yet, and probably copy your comment there as well.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest end easiest way I found is using a program called [VB6InstallerSetup](http://nuke.vbcorner.net/Articles/VB60/VisualStudio6Installer/tabid/93/language/en-US/Default.aspx).

You just follow the steps in the wizard and it does everything for you.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/visual-basic/mouse-wheel-events-do-not-work) is a fix to get the mouse wheel to work after the install.

Comment: The program I use to get the mouse wheel working in VB6 is [VBScroll](https://github.com/hlizard/VBScroll).  Just run it before you start VB6 (or actually even afterwards), and that's it - the scroll wheel works just like you'd want it to.